# AVD android 30 stuck boot loop after remount

Tags: android, adb, android-virtual-device

I'm trying to enable write access to an android emulator in order to push file into `/system` but I meet boot loop after using `adb remount` `adb reboot`.

I'm using avd image android 30, arc x86-64.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/232234/why-adb-remount-retruns-remount-failed-on-android-emulator

Comment: Nah. Seem this post is another issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by disabling verify on android emulator.

Command: `adb shell avbctl disable-verification`